# Applets: What's saved on the client's machine?

Tags: java, class, applet

I have an applet that when started, it makes a call to 3 different classes asking them for variables.

So, what's stored on the client's machine? just the Applet file or also the class files that the applet requires when it starts?

Comment: Applet file is generally a `.jar` which has applet classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM will download and cache all classes (whether or not they are in a Jar) before running the applet.